# ForEach TreeNode.Nodes Pulls Out Null Node

Tags: c#, recursion, null, nullreferenceexception

I have two recursive methods that are meant to check/uncheck all of the `TreeNodes` in a .NET `TreeView`  The methods are very simple:

```
private void SetAllNodes(TreeNode rootNode, bool value)
{
    rootNode.Checked = value;
    foreach (TreeNode node in rootNode.Nodes)
        SetAllNodes(node, value);
}

private void SetAllNodes(TreeView root, bool value)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in root.Nodes)
        SetAllNodes(node, value);
}
```

I call it like this:

`SetAllNodes(this.myTreeView, true);`

Anyway, this has worked fine for some time, but all of a sudden, I got a `null reference exception`.  After doing some debugging, I noticed during the `foreach` loop of the **second** function, at about the second iteration, a `null` `TreeNode` is returned.

Even more strangely, if I replace the `foreach` loop with the following code, the error goes away:

```
for (int i = 0; i < root.Nodes.Count; i++)
{
   TreeNode node = root.Nodes[i];
   SetAllNodes(node, value);
}
```

Any ideas why this is occurring?  I've debugged as much as I can, but the simple fact is that I am getting a `null` item from my `foreach` loop.

**Edit**
As requested, here is the stack trace:

```
MyProgram.exe!MyProgram.UI.frmFilter.SetAllNodes(System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode rootNode = null, bool value = false) Line 457 + 0x7 bytes    C#
MyProgram.exe!MyProgram.UI.frmFilter.SetAllNodes(System.Windows.Forms.TreeView root = {System.Windows.Forms.TreeView}, bool value = false) Line 450 + 0x6a bytes    C#
MyProgram.exe!MyProgram.UI.frmFilter.btnNone_Click(object sender = {Text = "None"}, System.EventArgs e = {X = 36 Y = 5 Button = Left}) Line 604 C#
[External Code] 
MyProgram.exe!MyProgram.Program.Main(string[] args = {string[0]}) Line 33 + 0x1d bytes  C#
[External Code]
```

Comment: Can you post the exact stack trace?

Comment: @MarkByers: Yes, I have posted it. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a SSCCE (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22762/159703)

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that `rootNode.Checked = value` is changing the structure of the internal collection, so the enumerator (`foreach`) is somehow returning a reference to a node that moved. Ideally an InvalidOperationException would be thrown with the message "collection was modified." Without a better understanding of what the Checked property setter is doing, using a `for` loop is probably a good work around.